# Symphony 5 installation on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: symfony, ubuntu

I am trying to find the instructions on how to install Symfony version 5.4 on my Ubuntu 20.4 - Apache2 - PHP 7.4 - MySql V8 - server, preferably without using composer. Most of what I have found are outdated and I have checked Symfony website as well. I checked here:

```
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#symfony-lts-versions
```

And found also found these at their website:

```
symfony new my_project_directory --version="5.4.*"

composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"5.4.*" my_project_directory
```

But as I understand it, doesn't symfony need to be installed first before creating a project ??

Answer (score 0):

Using modern PHP, with a framework - or any libraries, and without Composer is 'Not A Thing'.

You may also be confusing `symfony`, the command line tool ('symfony-cli'), downloadable from https://symfony.com/download (or it can be installed and updated using the native `apt` package manager with the instructions on the download page), and the framework, which pulls in various other libraries that are used, via Composer.

The two commands you show are doing the same thing, the symfony-cli tool actually runs `composer`, with a slightly friendlier set of options, and adds some other functionality - but it's nothing that you could not do yourself.

You will need to install composer, though, if you have the symfony-cli tool, it will attempt to download it if composer can't be found and run.

Comment: Thank you for responding. You clarified some items for me. If I use the symfony-cli tool, can composer be uninstalled  after installing symfony ? The client absolutely does not want composer on their server - they do not composer updating  etc. So if I do this command:

Comment: Based on your link -  the first command: curl -1sLf 'https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/symfony/stable/setup.deb.sh' | sudo -E bash
sudo apt install symfony-cli   - installs symfony and the second: symfony new my_project_directory --version="5.4.*" -  creates the project using version 5??

Comment: @MarthaJSayers You don't create projects directly on servers.  You would create the project on a development machine and then use one of a variety of other approaches to upload it to your server for deployment.  Ask your client how they install other applications on their server.

Comment: @cerad -Thank you for responding.  I will be developing 'locally' (using localhost) and not on a development nor a production server. In my 34 yrs of experience, I have never directly develop on a production server - only a development server. For the last decade, not even on a development server  - localhost only.

Comment: @MarthaJSayers Okay but why are you asking how to create a project on a server then?

Comment: @Cerad -  No where I did indicate I was using a server. I am developing locally. It does not have to be installed on a 'server' in order to use it.

Comment: @MarthaJSayers I was going off of `The client absolutely does not want composer on their server - they do not composer updating etc` in conjunction with your rather mysterious requirement not to use composer.  My mistake I guess.  Hope you got things working.

Comment: @Cerad - no offense given....none taken. Maybe they had a bad experience with ??? I did finally install everything correctly and all seems well.